# node js SQL Insert Query with Constructor / JSON text as values parameter

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest, sql-insert

First real app and I'm stuck trying to insert a new row into SQL.

```
//This is the API endpoint 
Sponsor.create = (newSponsor, result)=> {

  var sqlStmt = 'insert into sponsors (SponsorName, SponsorState, SponsorDesc, pnfpExperience, Status) values ?'
        
  sql.query(sqlStmt, [newSponsor], (err, res)=> {
         
    if(err) {
    console.log(" error: ", err);
    result(null, err);
  }
  else{
    console.log(res);
    result(null, res);
   
  }
  });
  };
```

request.body returns the JSON text but not an array of values that can be used in the query.  I keep getting a COUNT error or syntax error.  I've tried JSON.parse but I get an undefined error. I know there has to be a simple way to convert the JSON text to the right format but I don't know what I'm missing. The "findAll" and "findById" routes work and I can insert static values. I've also tried "newSponsor"  with and without brackets. I'll refine the connection method in time but I'm just trying to understand why this doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Controller.js for Reference
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  const new_sponsor = new Sponsor(req.body);
      //handles null error
      if(req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0){
        res.status(400).send({ error:true, message: 'Please provide all required field' });
      }else{
                
      Sponsor.create(new_sponsor, function(err, sponsor) {
        if (err)
        res.send(err);
        res.json({error:false,message:"Sponsor added successfully!",data:sponsor});
      });
      }
      };
```

Comment: `insert into sponsors (SponsorName, SponsorState, SponsorDesc, pnfpExperience, Status)` has five columns but `values ?` is a single value. Have you tried `values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`?

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning - I have tried that but it seems that newSponsor is only passing 1element -- it needs to pass 5.